# Can we add another UniqueWork in queue of other UniqueWork with WorkManager

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Let say i have started this UniqueWork with [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced):-

```
var workContinuation: WorkContinuation = WorkManager.getInstance()
                .beginUniqueWork(AppConstants.FILE_CREATOR_TAG,
                        ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND,
                        firstOneTimeWorkRequest)
```

Now at this point, our application user may want to start another UniqueWork work for some other task but that task should be added in queue of above work task.

```
var workContinuation: WorkContinuation = WorkManager.getInstance()
                    .beginUniqueWork(AppConstants.FILE_DISTRIBUTE_TAG,
                            ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND,
                            fileDistrubuteTimeWorkRequest)
```

Now how can i tell WorkManager that this UniqueWork AppConstants.FILE_DISTRIBUTE_TAG should in the queue of this AppConstants.FILE_CREATOR_TAG.

I don't want to use Observable solution in which I can track that this `AppConstants.FILE_CREATOR_TAG` worker done and start `AppConstants.FILE_DISTRIBUTE_TAG`.

Answer (score 3):

You should specify identical `uniqueWorkName` for both workers. Refer to `beginUniqueWork` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html#beginUniqueWork(java.lang.String,%2520androidx.work.ExistingWorkPolicy,%2520androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequest)):

> The `uniqueWorkName` uniquely identifies this set of work.
>
> If this method determines that new work should be enqueued and run, all records of previous work with `uniqueWorkName` will be pruned. If this method determines that new work should NOT be run, then the entire chain will be considered a no-op.
>
> If any work in the chain fails or is cancelled, all of its dependent work inherits that state and will never run. This is particularly important if you are using `APPEND` as your [ExistingWorkPolicy](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ExistingWorkPolicy.html).

Therefore, your code should be written like this:

```
var workContinuation: WorkContinuation = WorkManager.getInstance()
                .beginUniqueWork(AppConstants.SOME_UNIQUE_NAME,
                        ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND,
                        firstOneTimeWorkRequest)

// ...

var workContinuation: WorkContinuation = WorkManager.getInstance()
                .beginUniqueWork(AppConstants.SOME_UNIQUE_NAME,
                        ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND,
                        fileDistrubuteTimeWorkRequest)
```

Comment: I can not use SOME_UNIQUE_NAME work my two Continuation work because with this, If i want to cancel only First Unique work than it will cancel both because they have same beginUniqueWork name assign to them. In my requirement i want both to have separate uniueWorkName, Because i also want to check which work group is currently running.